# Cannot convert value "27/02/2028 12:50" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Tags: powershell, datetime

This is the first time that I try to use a script on Windows Server 2022.

I have an error about the date.time format:

```
Cannot convert value "27/02/2028 12:50" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
At C:\Utils\PKIscripts\CertExpiryNotify.ps1:125 char:6
+      $Certexpirydate = [datetime](Get-date $importall[$i].'Certificat ...
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastParseTargetInvocationWithFormatProvider
```

The instruction that generate the error is :

```
#cycle through array and search for matching cetificates
for($i=0;$i -lt $importall.Count;$i++)
{
     #for each object, get the "certificate expirate date" and convert to [datetime]
     $Certexpirydate = [datetime](Get-date $importall[$i].'Certificate Expiration Date' -Format $formatdata)
```

This Script should retrieve the Certificate date, and send an alert via mail if any certificate are expiring.
Follow the link where I have copy it:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/core-infrastructure-and-security/script-to-send-email-alerts-on-expiring-certificates-for/ba-p/1169438

Comment: did you make sure that `$formatdata` evaluates to the correct input date/time format?

Comment: Same question as FObersteiner, and it would be extremely helpful to share the value of `$formatdata` - can't debug code we can't see.

Comment: `$formatdata = 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm'`. Without that, 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm' is assumed

Comment: The value of $formatdata is: Get-Variable formatdata

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                 
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                 
formatdata                dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm