# Cannot convert value "27/02/2028 12:50" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." Any Ideas?

Tags: powershell, datetime

This is the first time that I try to use a script on Windows Server 2022.

I have an error about the date.time format:

```
Cannot convert value "27/02/2028 12:50" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
At C:\Utils\PKIscripts\CertExpiryNotify.ps1:125 char:6
+      $Certexpirydate = [datetime](Get-date $importall[$i].'Certificat ...
```

This is the first time that I try to use a script on Windows Server 2022.

I have an error about the date.time format:

Cannot convert value "27/02/2028 12:50" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
At C:\Utils\PKIscripts\CertExpiryNotify.ps1:125 char:6

```
+      $Certexpirydate = [datetime](Get-date $importall[$i].'Certificat ...

+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) \[\], RuntimeException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastParseTargetInvocationWithFormatProvider
```

The instruction that generate the error is :

```
#cycle through array and search for matching cetificates
for($i=0;$i -lt $importall.Count;$i++)
{
#for each object, get the "certificate expirate date" and convert to \[datetime\]
$Certexpirydate = \[datetime\](Get-date $importall\[$i\].'Certificate Expiration Date' -Format $formatdata)
```

This Script should retrieve the Certificate date, and send an alert via mail if any certificate are expiring. Follow the link where I have copy it:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/core-infrastructure-and-security/script-to-send-email-alerts-on-expiring-certificates-for/ba-p/1169438

This Script should retrieve the Certificate date, and send an alert via mail if any certificate are expiring. Follow the link where I have copy it:

The value of $formatdata is:

```
Get-Variable formatdata Name Value ---- ----- formatdata dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm

$cultureinfo = Get-Culture

$formatdata = "$($cultureinfo.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern) $($cultureinfo.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern)"
```

Using Debug the $cultureinfo =

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
cultureinfo                    it-IT
```

And      Formatdata

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
formatdata                     dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm
```

The Original script is:

```
<#Sample scripts provided are not supported under any Microsoft standard support program or service. The sample scripts are provided AS IS without warranty of any kind. Microsoft disclaims all implied warranties including, without limitation, any implied warranties of merchantability or of fitness for a particular purpose. The entire risk arising out of the use or performance of the sample scripts and documentation remains with you. In no event shall Microsoft, its authors, or anyone else involved in the creation, production, or delivery of the scripts be liable for any damages whatsoever (including, without limitation, damages for loss of business profits, business interruption, loss of business information, or other pecuniary loss) arising out of the use of or inability to use the sample scripts or documentation, even if Microsoft has been advised of the possibility of such damages.#>
#functions
Function Send-CertificateList
{
    #initialize email pre-reqs
    $FromAddress = 'xxxxx@dyyyy.it'
    $ToAddress  = 'test@dyyyy.it'
    $MessageSubject = "Certificate expiration reminder from $env:COMPUTERNAME.$env:USERDNSDOMAIN"
    $SendingServer = 'fffffff.it'
    $SmtpServerPort = "25"

    #Test if SMTP server is responding
    if(Test-Connection -Cn $SendingServer -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -ea 0 -quiet){
            #Send email
            Send-MailMessage -From $FromAddress -To $ToAddress -Subject $MessageSubject -Body $mailbody -BodyAsHtml -SmtpServer $SendingServer -Port $SmtpServerPort
    }else{
            #Error Handling
            write-host -object 'No connection to SMTP server. Failed to send email!'
    }
}

Function Send-Certificatemail
{
    #initialize email pre-reqs
    $FromAddress = 'xxxxx@dyyyy.it'
    $CCAddress  = 'test@dyyyy.it'
    $MessageSubject = "Certificate expiration reminder from $env:COMPUTERNAME.$env:USERDNSDOMAIN"
    $SendingServer = 'fffffff.it'
    $SmtpServerPort = "25"

    #Test if SMTP server is responding
    if(Test-Connection -Cn $SendingServer -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -ea 0 -quiet){
            #Send email
            Send-MailMessage -From $FromAddress -To $ToAddress -Cc $CCAddress -Subject $MessageSubject -Body $Emailbody -BodyAsHtml -SmtpServer $SendingServer -Port $SmtpServerPort
    }else{
            #Error Handling
            write-host -object 'No connection to SMTP server. Failed to send email!'
    }
}
```

## --------------------------------------------------

```
#HTML Style
$style = @'
<style>body{font-family:`"Calibri`",`"sans-serif`"; font-size: 14px;}
@font-face 
       {font-family:`"Cambria Math`"; 
       panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;}
@font-face 
       {font-family:Calibri; 
       panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;} 
@font-face 
       {font-family:Tahoma; 
       panose-1:2 11 6 4 3 5 4 4 2 4;}
       table{border: 1px solid black; border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;}
       th{border: 1px solid black; background: #dddddd; padding: 5px; }
       td{border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px; }
       .crtsn{font-weight: bold; color: blue; }
       .crtexp{font-weight: bold; color: red; }
       .crtcn{font-weight: bold; color: orange; }
       </style>
'@

# --------------------------------------------------
#variables
#filter template list
$filterlist ="User_1","I2","I3","W4","I5","DUMMYTST"
#setup duration
$duration = 30
#setup strDate with yyyyMMdd-HHmmss
#$strDate = get-date -format yyyyMMdd-HHmmss
$strDate = get-date -format "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"
#create unique export file name
#$exportFileName = "certificates_" + $strDate + ".csv"
$exportFileName = "c:\utils\pkiscripts\certlist.csv"
#date of Now
$now = (Get-Date)
#date of Then
$Then = (Get-Date).AddDays($duration)
#empty mailbody
$mailbody = ""
#empty array initialization
$table = @()

# --------------------------------------------------
#variables

#export certificates to CSV
certutil.exe -view csv > $exportFileName

#Import certificate info where Serial Number is not "empty" with various properties
$importall = Import-Csv $exportFileName | Where-Object {$_.'Serial Number' -notcontains 'EMPTY'} | Select-Object -Property 'Request ID','Serial Number','Requester Name','Certificate Expiration Date','Certificate Template','Request Common Name','Request Disposition' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#Run through each ObjectID  to get the Certificate Template Name
foreach ($OID in (get-catemplate).Oid)
{
    #populate the field "Certificate Template"
    $importall | where-object "certificate template" -match $OID | foreach-object {
        #ensure whitespaces removed
        $_.'Certificate Template' = ($_.'Certificate Template').replace($OID+" ","")
    }

}
#filter only required certificates based on $filterlist
$importall = $importall | where-object "certificate template" -in $filterlist

#build email body
$mailbody += '<html><head><meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">' + $style + '</head><body>'
$mailbody += "The certificate expiry details:<br />"

#collect cultureinfo for short date and time pattern
$cultureinfo = Get-Culture
$formatdata = "$($cultureinfo.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern) $($cultureinfo.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern)"

#mail body template
$mailbody += '<p>'
$mailbody += 'Hello Reader, '+"<br />"
$mailbody += 'Please find below the list of certificaes Expiring in next ' + $duration + ' days' + "</span><br />"
$mailbody += '</p>'

#cycle through array and search for matching cetificates
for($i=0;$i -lt $importall.Count;$i++)
{
     #for each object, get the "certificate expirate date" and convert to [datetime]
     $Certexpirydate = [datetime](Get-date $importall[$i].'Certificate Expiration Date' -Format $formatdata)
     #perform comparison
     If(($Certexpirydate -gt $now) -and ($Certexpirydate -le $then))

        {
            #write to console
            write-host -object 'Certificate ID:' $importall[$i].'Request ID' 'with Serial Number:' $importall[$i].'Serial Number' 'will expire in ' -NoNewline; write-host -object ([datetime]($importall[$i].'Certificate Expiration Date') - (get-date)) ' Days!'-ForegroundColor Red
            write-host -object 'This certificate has DN: ' -NoNewline; write-host -object $importall[$i].'Request Distinguished Name' -ForegroundColor DarkYellow
            write-host -object 'Please don`t forget to renew this certificate before expiration date: ' -NoNewline; write-host -object $importall[$i].'Certificate Expiration Date' -ForegroundColor Red "`n"

            #save info in table array
            $table += $importall[$i] | Sort-Object 'Certificate Expiration Date' | Select-Object -Property 'Request ID','Serial Number','Requester Name','Certificate Template','Certificate Expiration Date','Request Common Name','Issued Email Address'
        }
}

#mailbody html formatting
$mailbody += '<p><table>'
$mailbody += '<th>Request ID</th><th>Serial Number</th><th>Requester Name</th><th>Requested CN</th><th>Certificate Template</th><th>Expiration date</th>'

#run through each row
foreach($row in $table)
    {
        #create necessary row information
        $mailbody += "<tr><td>" + $row.'Request ID' + "</td><td>" + $row.'Serial Number' + "</td><td>" + $row.'Requester Name' + "</td><td>" + $row.'Request Common Name' + "</td><td>" + $row.'Certificate Template' + "</td><td>" + $row.'Certificate Expiration Date' + "</td></tr>"
    }
#closing html tags
$mailbody += '</table></p>'
$mailbody += '</body>'
$mailbody += '</html>'

#if there are matching certificates found send email
if($table.Count -gt '0')
    {
        #send email
        Send-CertificateList
    }

#run through each row
foreach($row in $table)
{
    #if email address exist
    if($($row.'Issued Email Address') -like "*@*")
    {
        #populate to address and email body
        $ToAddress  = $row.'Issued Email Address'
        $emailbody =  "Hello Reader,<br>
                            <br>
                            The certificate requested by you is about to expire :

                            <br>
                            Details <br>
                            -------------------- <br>
                            $row
                            <Br>
                            <br>
                            Thanks"
        #send mail
        Send-Certificatemail
    }
}
```

I hace tryed to change the Get-date as suggested in this way:

$Certexpirydate = (Get-date $importall[$i].'Certificate Expiration Date' $formatdata)

and I got another error:

Get-Date : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm'.
At C:\Utils\PKIscripts\CertExpiryNotify.ps1:126 char:25

- ... pirydate = (Get-date $importall[$i].'Certificate Expiration Date' $fo ...
- ```
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Date], ParameterBindingException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetDateCommand

Write-Host : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '4'.
At C:\Utils\PKIscripts\CertExpiryNotify.ps1:132 char:13

- ```
          write-host -object 'Certificate ID:' $importall[$i].'Requ ...
  ```
- ```
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Write-Host], ParameterBindingException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteHostCommand

Cannot convert value "25/08/2024 12:42" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
At C:\Utils\PKIscripts\CertExpiryNotify.ps1:132 char:161

- ... -NoNewline; write-host -object ([datetime]($importall[$i].'Certificat ...
- ```
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastParseTargetInvocationWithFormatProvider

Thank you to All that help me to solve the Date format problem. I have try to run the script, and now I got another different error:

Write-Host : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '4'.
At C:\Utils\PKIscripts\CertExpiryNotify.ps1:133 char:13

- ```
          write-host -object 'Certificate ID:' $importall[$i].'Requ ...
  ```
- ```
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Write-Host], ParameterBindingException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteHostCommand

Cannot convert value "25/08/2024 12:42" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
At C:\Utils\PKIscripts\CertExpiryNotify.ps1:133 char:161

- ... -NoNewline; write-host -object ([datetime]($importall[$i].'Certificat ...
- ```
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastParseTargetInvocationWithFormatProvider

This certificate has DN:
Please don`t forget to renew this certificate before expiration date: Write-Host : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '

The command the give the error is:

write-host -object 'Certificate ID:' $importall[$i].'Request ID' 'with Serial Number:' $importall[$i].'Serial Number' 'will expire in ' -NoNewline; write-host -object ([datetime]($importall[$i].'Certificate Expiration Date') - (get-date)) ' Days!'-ForegroundColor Red

If you prefer that  I open a new topic for this new issue let me know.

Comment: The error is clear. Where did the string come from and what's its actual content? PowerShell's [Get-Date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date?view=powershell-7.3) returns a DateTime object, not a string. Post a script that actually reproduces the problem.

Comment: why don't you add those details to [your first question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77023531/10197418)? You can always [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77023531/edit) your questions...

Comment: If you want to convert a string in the format ```27/02/2028 12:50``` into a ```datetime``` object you can do this: ```[datetime]::ParseExact("27/02/2028 12:50", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", [CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)```, but I think you might want to look at where that string is coming from because it might already be a datetime object to start with before it gets turned into a string...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaving the formatting artifacts aside:

The implication of your symptom is that the argument you're passing to [`Get-Date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date) already *is* recognized as a `[datetime]` instance, so you can simply omit the `-Format` argument and the `[datetime]` cast:

```bash
# If Get-Date recognizes the (positionally implied) -Date argument
# as a [datetime] - typically by conversion *from a string* - it outputs
# a [datetime] instance.
$Certexpirydate = Get-Date $importall[$i].'Certificate Expiration Date'
```

---

In general (there's no ambiguity in your case), if an argument string can be *misinterpreted* based on whether the day or the month component comes first - or isn't recognized at all - you can use [`[datetime]::ParseExact()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime.ParseExact) with an exact description of the input string format, as suggested by [mclayton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3156906/mclayton):

```bash
$Certexpirydate = 
  [datetime]::ParseExact(
    $importall[$i].'Certificate Expiration Date', 
    'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm', 
    [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture
  )
```

---

Finally, as an aside: if you want to create a specific *string* representation *after* having created a `[datetime]` instance, pass the format string to its [`.ToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime.ToString) method (using `[datetime]::Now` as an example `[datetime]` instance here):

```bash
# ->, e.g.: '05/09/2023 10:51'
[datetime]::Now.ToString('dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm', [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)
```

Note:

- If you omit [`[cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) from the calls above, the rules of the *current* culture apply (as reflected in [`Get-Culture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-culture) and [`$PSCulture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#psculture)), which *may* result in the `/` and `:` placeholders in the format string getting replaced with culture-specific separators (e.g, `-` and `.`)
- An alternative is to *escape* these placeholders, e.g. as `\/` and `\:`